# looping a list of inputs and statements

Tags: java

Any help on looping these statements. I am new to this and I am having some trouble. I am trying to make it so that the gradebook will take the grades of five children before giving a class average. Just need help with the looping.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class gradebook {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        float discussionweight, hwweight, examweight, discussion, hw, exam, finalaverage, again;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the students name: ");
        String student = scan.next();

        System.out.print ("Enter the weight of the discussions as an integer: ");
        discussionweight = scan.nextFloat();

        // Prompts for the discussions grade
        System.out.print ("Enter the score of the discussion as an integer: ");
        discussion = scan.nextFloat();

        // Prompts for the weight of the homework grade in an integer
        System.out.print ("Enter the weight of the homework as an integer: ");
        hwweight = scan.nextFloat();

        // Prompts for hw grade
        System.out.print ("Enter the hw grade: ");
        hw = scan.nextFloat();

        System.out.print("Enter the weight of the exam as an integer");
        examweight = scan.nextFloat();

        System.out.print("Enter the exam grade");
        exam = scan.nextFloat();




        // Calculate and print the final, weighted average.
        finalaverage = (((discussionweight * discussion) + (hw * hwweight) + (exam * examweight)) / 100);

        if (finalaverage >= 90)
        System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is an A."); 
        else if (finalaverage >= 80)
        System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is a B.");
        else if (finalaverage >= 70)
        System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is a C.");
        else if (finalaverage >= 60)
        System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is a D.");
        else if (finalaverage >= 10)
        System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is an F.");


        System.out.println ("The final average is "+ finalaverage);
        System.out.println ("Would you like to continue? Enter 0 to exit and anything else to continue.");
        String again = scan.nextFloat();

        while (again != 0) {
            finalaverage += again;
        }



    }
```

Comment: If you want the entire thing to loop -- as in from `float discussionWeight...` until `String again = scan.nextFloat()`, then you should enclose all of those statements in the block of a loop. So your `while` loop at the bottom should enclose all those statements above it.

Comment: Well - for one your program wouldn't compile - `again` is declared twice...

Comment: I suggest that you break this up into more manageable methods.

Answer (score 2):

As per Java documentation

> The while statement continually executes a block of statements while a
>   particular condition is true. Its syntax can be expressed as:
>
> while (expression) {
>
> ```
>  statement(s)
> ```
>
> }
>
> The while statement evaluates expression, which must return a boolean
>   value. If the expression evaluates to true, the while statement
>   executes the statement(s) in the while block. The while statement
>   continues testing the expression and executing its block until the
>   expression evaluates to false.

Consider all calculation logic and taking user inputs as `statement(s)` in above example. While loop will execute as long as `expression`  is returns `true` boolean value. So you can add `again!=0` as `expression` because when user press 0 program should  be terminated.

Also again variable should be initialized with non zero value so that first time while condition  satisfied. You have to use do-while loop otherwise.

scan.nextFloat() treats user input as float. Use it only when user input is float. If you  declare  `again` as int then you have to use scan.nextInt();

```
public class gradebook {


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    float discussionweight, hwweight, examweight, discussion, hw, exam, finalaverage;
    int again=-1;

    while( again!=0){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the students name: ");
    String student = scan.next();

    System.out.print ("Enter the weight of the discussions as an integer: ");
    discussionweight = scan.nextFloat();

    // Prompts for the discussions grade
    System.out.print ("Enter the score of the discussion as an integer: ");
    discussion = scan.nextFloat();

    // Prompts for the weight of the homework grade in an integer
    System.out.print ("Enter the weight of the homework as an integer: ");
    hwweight = scan.nextFloat();

    // Prompts for hw grade
    System.out.print ("Enter the hw grade: ");
    hw = scan.nextFloat();

    System.out.print("Enter the weight of the exam as an integer");
    examweight = scan.nextFloat();

    System.out.print("Enter the exam grade");
    exam = scan.nextFloat();




    // Calculate and print the final, weighted average.
    finalaverage = (((discussionweight * discussion) + (hw * hwweight) + (exam * examweight)) / 100);

    if (finalaverage >= 90)
    System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is an A."); 
    else if (finalaverage >= 80)
    System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is a B.");
    else if (finalaverage >= 70)
    System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is a C.");
    else if (finalaverage >= 60)
    System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is a D.");
    else if (finalaverage >= 10)
    System.out.println(student +"'s " + "final grade is an F.");


    System.out.println ("The final average is "+ finalaverage);
    System.out.println ("Would you like to continue? Enter 0 to exit and anything else to continue.");
     again = scan.nextInt();


    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of giving the answer away, help the OP to understand the issue that he has. he or she does not even know difference between String and float type.

Answer (score 1):

do it this way
As you want to continue using the logic again and again you need to loop over it until the conditions for exit becomes true. In this case the loop will continue executing until the user input is 0 then the program exits.

```
while(true) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the students name: ");
    String student = scan.nextLine();//change to nextLine()
    // rest all same
    System.out.println("The final average is " + finalaverage);
    System.out.println("Would you like to continue? Enter 0 to exit 
                                     and anything else to continue.");
    again = scan.nextFloat();
    if(again == 0)// if input is zero it will continue or else it will exit
       break;
}
```

change this `String again = scan.nextFloat();` to `again = scan.nextFloat();`
as you already have a variable by the name again of type float moreover nextFloat() gives you an input of type float then why do you need the String in that case.

Comment: Instead of giving the answer away, help the OP to understand the issue that he has. he or she does not even know difference between String and float type.

Comment: @KickButtowski sorry man i dint notice that things i thought she was just stuck over the while thing

Comment: it is k no need to be sorry. if I were, I would take out my code

Comment: @KickButtowski students really  :/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redeclare a variable in Java with the same name which you would have declared earlier. In your program at the line `String again = scan.nextFloat();` you are trying to do this. And also you are trying to assign a float value to string variable which is not allowed. Regarding your question of looping you can use a simple do while(..) loop as shown in the below code to continue with another  student data. I am not sure if you need the line `finalaverage+= again;` .Please check on this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class gradebook {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float discussionweight, hwweight, examweight, discussion, hw, exam, finalaverage, again ;

        do {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the students name: ");
            String student = scan.next();

            ....// same as your code.

            System.out.println ("The final average is "+ finalaverage);
            System.out.println ("Would you like to continue? Enter 0 to exit and anything else to continue.");
            again = scan.nextFloat();


            finalaverage += again;
        } while (again != 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of giving the answer away, help the OP to understand the issue that he has. he or she does not even know difference between String and float type.

Comment: @KickButtowski you are correct. But I feel the above code is self explanatory and would be difficult to put across in words.

Comment: i am sorry to tell you. it is not. he or she does not even know the difference between float and String type. how you expect that he or she knows your code?

Comment: instead of giving the answer away, try to explain the issues. I am more than happy to vote u up

Comment: @KickButtowski I got your point absolutely. I was of the assumption that he was wondering how to put a loop across but I think I misunderstood his question. I will surely edit my answer. And also I dont know what is the use of finalaverage += again; . This line is not required I believe. Whats your thoughts on this?

Comment: I really don't know. it just show the op does not know the fundamentals. go to the op page and see the op asked same question

Comment: @KickButtowski Yup. I mentioned this in the above answer and I also incorporated your suggestions. Please feel free to add on if I missed out anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down into what needs to happen.

Let `N` be the number of students `5`,

- Collect the final grade for a student

  - Collect scores of the assignments
  - Average the scores together
- Repeat until you have `N` students' grades
- Let `average` be the average of the student's grades

---

Break this problem down into smaller parts. Consider *"Let `average` be the average of the student's grades"*. What we know is:

- A grade is a `float`, so we need a method (or "smaller part", as I called it earlier) that will average `float` values.

In Java, you would express such a method something like this:

```
static float average(List<Float> terms) { 
    float total = 0;        // Begin with a total 0 - any summation begins here
    for (float t : terms) { // For every float t in terms
        total += t;         // add t to the total 
    }
    return total / terms.size(); // return total divided by the number of terms
}
```

And then test and make sure this does what you want here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // `test` is now a list of floats, we would expect average to be 
    // effectively equal to 2.5
    List<Float> test = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2.0f, 2.5f, 3.0f)); 
    float actual = average(test); // This calls the average method above
    System.out.println(actual);   // and outputs to console, which prints 2.5
}
```

---

How is an average method and it's test to make sure it does what you expect useful to you? Well, for one, you now have a way of collecting a list of `float` values (with `List<Float>`). So we can express the breakdown from above in a little more detail now.

- Declare a `List<Float>`, like `List<Float> grades = new ArrayList<Float>`.
- Collect the final grade for a student, by

  - Collecting the scores of the assignments, then
  - average the scores together, *(Hint: Maybe you need another different `average()` method that handles weighted averages)*
  - and store that average in `grades`, for example `grades.add(average)`
- Repeat until you have `N` students' grades
- Use average to get the final output, like `float classAverage = average(grades)`

Everything about programming is about breaking down problems into their constituent components, then further breaking them down until you have reasonbly sized (read: *small*) problems that can be solved simply, then put together into a larger program.

[`List<E>` Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

[`ArrayList<E>` Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)